# If(value of input==number)

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I tried to create a little program,
I had a little problem with if(value of input == x) else ...

Can someone please help m ?

```
Int main () {...  int choice;
    do{
    cout <<"choose from the list below to make the convertion"<<endl;
    cout <<"1 : € to $, 2 :$ to €,3 :$ to £,4: £ to$\n";
    cin >>choice;

           if (choice =='1') {cout << "Pls enter € value to convert to $."<<endl;

           cin >>value;

            cout <<"euro\t\t to\t\t dollard\n"; cout <<value<<"\t\t\t\t"<<value*diff<<endl; } 

           else if (choice=='2'){.....
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You only stated that you had a problem, but you didn't explain what that problem is.

Comment: You're confusing numbers and characters.

Comment: Well the problem is when i type for example 2 or 3 it executes the first statement if (choice = 1).

Comment: If you actually compile the code you've shown us, it will be rejected by the compiler because you write `Int` rather than `int`. Your original title used `=` (assignment) rather than `==` (comparison), which is a common problem, but your code correctly uses `==`.

Comment: The digit `'1'` is not the same thing as the number `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are comparing an int variable (choice), with a character literal ('1'). When you compare with '1', you are actually comparing with the ASCII value of the character '1', which is 49.

So to solve your problem, replace

```
if (choice =='1')
```

with

```
if (choice ==1)
```

Comment: Misleading. Character literals are of type `char` in C++, but `char` is an integral type. You certainly can compare an `int` value to a `char` variable. The problem is a logic error, not a type error. `choice` was read as an integer. (Defining `choice` as a `char` would be another solution.)

Comment: Oops, thank you for the correction - I've edited my answer. Maybe I'm not as good at c++ as I thought...